# My javascript isn't recognized in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

It's the first day for me to try javascript, and I use chrome developer tool now. The following example should print "My First JavaScript" to the website, but nothing is there. I put `document.write("My First JavaScript")` in the console, it just put "My First JavaScript" outside the `<script>` label, then prints the right result. I do google search to know that JavaScript is surrounded by a `<script>` and `</script>` tag, but it seems doesn't work in html. Please help me with this. Thanks!

```
<html>
 <body>
   <script>
     document.write("My First JavaScript");
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why, why, why do you start learning JavaScript with `document.write`? Why didn't you choose some sane and modern tutorials - like [this](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html), for example? Anyway, it works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't print anything to console: it just transforms the page instead.

Comment: The console is strictly for JavaScript, not HTML. Try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I don't get this question at all, it definitely works on Chrome, at least from what I understood from the question. http://jsfiddle.net/MNWcP/

Comment: @raina77ow, thanks for the explanation and the tutorial! I searched "hello world for javascript", it just pops up with the function document.write. Keep learning it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a step back and listen to some of the advice in the comments here. As a Javascript newbie myself, I found the most helpful tutorials were the interactive lessons at [CodeAcademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/)

As for the actual code... what you describe is actually how it should work. Think of the console as being wrapped by those  tags. Essentially, it's as if you put the command into a text file and included it in a script tag as you would for other JavaScript.

Document.write will take an HTML document and render it to your screen. In this case you're only sending it a single string (a bit of text) and the browser is building out the rest of that HTML that you see to make it a valid document.

Comment: thanks Dave! I'm learning javascript from the very beginning, and I was a little confused about how the console worked with html. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.write("My First JavaScript");
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason for this to be considered a solution to the OP's problem? When `type` attribute is omitted, the `<script>` content is treated as JavaScript.

Comment: I think the default value is type="text/javascript". same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Java script tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Try learning from scratch.. Am doing it now.. :P

Comment: You might want to steer clear of that site. W3C schools (not affiliated with the actual W3C) is not known to be accurate and teaches bad practices. I'm partial to the Mozilla Developer Network documentation and for a tutorial it's hard to beat codeacademy. That said, best of luck learning this great language!